# SQL Server Express Stored procedure: Select, delete, insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am using below query to insert record into a table.

```
DELETE FROM Table1;

INSERT into Table1 (F1,f2,f3...) SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE......
```

The problem is, SELECT query took some time to fetch due to many conditions, while records are already deleted from Table1, live records may not be available for display in Client Side while waiting for SELECT query result and be inserted in table1.

I need to SELECT record first, then DELETE record from the table1, then insert the selected record to table1. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do it in a single transaction, then no changes will be visible until you commit the delete and the insert.

Comment: How does single transaction works? Will it perform delete from records but not committed? then proceed with insert into select? Then committing at the end performs delete, insert using result set loaded before committing?

Comment: The changes will be done at the moment each statement is executed, the `commit` will just make that visible to other transactions. See e.g. here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html

Comment: Sql Express. I tried @Hemang answer but it seems each statement needs to be commited first before executing another statement.

Comment: I have used a work around. I added field updatetimestamp which is getdate() during insert. So after insert, i will just delete records <> updatetimestamp

Comment: No, the whole point of a transaction is that you can execute a whole series of statements within a single transaction and you don't commit them until right at the end. In your case, within your transaction the records will appear to have been deleted after the first statement, but to anyone else looking at the database they will still appear to be there until you commit the transaction. I think you should maybe do some research on the concept  yourself so you fully understand what is happening.

Comment: It's not clear if that is actually the problem you're trying to solve though...your question wording is a bit ambiguous to be truthful. Are you trying to stop users inserting into table1 while you clear it down and repopulate it from another table? That seems a strange business process, but leaving that aside, perhaps the way to achieve it might be by locking the table while you run the delete and insert commands.

Comment: Thanks. I was early to judge when I didn't fully understand Transaction. This is just for client viewing. I just don't want an instance wherein dashboard will be empty because data is deleted and still waiting to be populated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use transaction like and also delete after insert but add somewhere criteria.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

   While (i<0)(while loop and so on condition.)
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM Table1 ;
     INSERT into Table1 (F1,f2,f3...) SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE......
   END

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: I think each transaction needs to be committed first? Delete commit, insert commit? Isn't it?

Comment: No, please add while loop and others perform all operation after commit . I have update solution.

Comment: What is the loop for?

Comment: Upvoted for showing the transaction syntax, but I agree, it's unclear why any loop would be needed here. What does `i` represent in this scenario?

Comment: it just displays how to use the loop, not proper syntax write down for a loop .

Comment: @HemangAghera I know that, but that wasn't what I asked. The question is: why did you include a loop in this code? What is the purpose of it? It should not be needed to achieve what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @@rowcount

```
Declare @row_count int
SELECT @row_count=count(*) FROM TABLE2 WHERE......
INSERT into Table1 (F1,f2,f3...) SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE......
DELETE TOP(@row_count) FROM Table1 ;
```

First get count how many records you want to insert the,
First data is inserted,
if data insertion success then data is delete 
other wise data won't be delete

So, every time data is available in table to show client

Comment: Doesn't work. All data gets deleted including newly inserted records.

Comment: you can check now

Comment: That will delete random records from Table1. I inserted a timestamp instead so i'll just delete records not equals to timestamp of current newly inserted records.